# Sequential Hypothesis Test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

Consider a random variable Y and the pair of simple hypotheses:

$H_0 : Y \sim N(0,10)$

$H_1 : Y \sim N(m,10)$

Here $m$ is an unknown mean which is sampled from a distribution $N(0,1)$ and then held fixed for ever.

Consider that you get to observe 100 samples of Y. For each sample $y_i$ observed, you are to decide whether $y_i$ was from $H_0$ or from $H_1$.

There can me two models here, in the batch case, you get to observe all $100$ samples and then you need to make a decision on each $y_i$, $1\leq i \leq 100$. Is this a well known detection theory problem? I am not able to find any reference on how to do this.

Alternatively, we consider a 'Sequential' testing of hypothesis (make decision on $y_i$ immediately as soon as it is sampled). Shouldn't I be able to use the knowledge of what decisions I made for say the first $10$ samples to be able to make better decisions in my $11^{th}$ sample? And yet I have not been able to find a good reference to deal with such a problem.

Note that although mean $m$ is fixed, its value is unknown. The only prior information available is that it is sampled from a gaussian.

Comment: You may want to read up on (a) Wald sequential probability ratio test and (b) sequential Bayesian inference. In (a) a decision is made after each observation (or fixed size batch of of obs) to Acc Ho, Rej Ho or take more data. Thus sample size becomes a random variable. In (b) the posterior distribution from one phase of Bayesian inference becomes the prior distribution for the next phase. // Your statement is a bit vague for either, but your general intent is along useful lines.

Comment: Thanks for the comments . For a) what if I am required to make a decision at every time step ? After further thought this seems to not be a binary hypothesis at all. It looks like if there are 100 times steps .there are $2^{100}$ possible hypothesis. Would that be right interpretation?

Comment: _Two hypotheses,_ process stops when you have enough data to choose one of them. Advantage is that the (random) sample size is has expected value less than would be necessary for a fixed-sample-size test. Disadvantage is that occasionally the random sample size turns out to be very large.

Comment: I understand that, however in my proposed setup, you are FORCED to make a decision for EVERY time step. There is no concept of "having enough confidence" or "waiting long enough" to decide.

Comment: Well then, you're using 'sequential testing' in a colloquial sense, which I thought might be technical. With that clarification, ignore Wald sequential probability ratio test. // Bayesian idea may still be useful. Even if you don't use a Bayesian model, it would seem silly to have to forget previous results when making current 'decision'. Is there any kind of practical situation that motivates this scheme of repeated deciding/guessing? Is the game over if you ever guess wrong?

Comment: well it was just something I sort of invented motivated by a completely unrelated problem which I won't go into here. Had wondered that surely someone would have analyzed such a problem in detail. And plus it seemed quite interesting to not think about!